# If Else AssignmentOperator Issues - Java

Tags: java, syntax-error

I'm a beginning student in a Java class, so this will probably seem stupid to you guys. Here's the code.

```
class CyclingResult implements IEvent {
  double time;
  int finishOrder;

  CyclingResult(double time, int finishOrder) {
    this.time = time;
    this.finishOrder = finishOrder;
  }

  public double pointsEarned() {
    return if (this.finishOrder == 1) {
      (this.time - 10);
    } else if (this.finishOrder == 2) {
      (this.time - 7);
    } else if (this.finishOrder == 3) {
      (this.time - 3);
    } else {
      this.time;
    }
  }
}
```

I get a set of 5 "Error: Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression"

I'm sure it's something stupid going on with my code, but the examples I can find are a little above my head to figure out the differences.

Comment: `if` is a statement, not an expression. So it doesn't have a value.

Comment: You cannot return an if (...) block. There are a few ways you could resolve this. An easy one to explain is to remove the "return" before the "if (this...) and place a "return" on the same line as and before every "(this.time - ...)

Comment: What I was attempting to do with that was produce a "score" based on this.time, unless the athlete was in first, second, or third place, in which case you would subtract a little from their score, kind of like golf.

edit: your fix worked, Savlon. Thank you so much. I never would have figured that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot return an `if` statement in Java.  Unlike other languages (such as Scala), an `if` statement is exactly that: a statement (with no value).

You instead need to return inside each if/else block separately.

```
public double pointsEarned() {
    if (this.finishOrder == 1) {
      return (this.time - 10);
    } else if (this.finishOrder == 2) {
      return (this.time - 7);
    } else if (this.finishOrder == 3) {
      return (this.time - 3);
    } else {
      return this.time;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest to what you're trying to do here is a nested conditional operator:

```
return (this.finishOrder == 1) ? (this.time - 10)
     : (this.finishOrder == 2) ? (this.time - 7)
     : (this.finishOrder == 3) ? (this.time - 3)
     : this.time;
```

You can't use `return if ...` because [`if` is a statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9), [not an expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17).

Comment: The practical reason not to use this is that you can't step through it with a debugger easily.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning the value properly. You must use return for each condition if you want to return the value immediately.

```
public double pointsEarned() {
    if (this.finishOrder == 1) {
        return (this.time - 10);
    } else if (this.finishOrder == 2) {
        return (this.time - 7);
    } else if (this.finishOrder == 3) {
        return (this.time - 3);
    }
    return this.time;
}
```

For multiple if/else-if statements you should consider using a switch statement:

```
public double pointsEarned() {
    switch (this.finishOrder) {
        case 1:
            return (this.time - 10);
        case 2:
            return (this.time - 7);
        case 3:
            return (this.time - 3);
        default:
            break;
    }
    return this.time;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do exactly what the OP is trying to do. It has a side effect of changing the value of a field; something the OP didn't ask for.